# mapping lists in ML

Tags: list, ml

I have a question about mapping lists in ML the problem seems to repeat itself, I have the current datatypes defined :

```
datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq);
datatype 'a generic_list = List of 'a list
                          |Seq of 'a seq;
```

i'm now trying to write the following function that's supposed to recieve a "'a generic_list" and return a "int generic_list:

```
val rec generic_map = fn (f,List(lst)) => if lst=nil then List([])                                             
      else List(f(List.hd(lst))::generic_map(f,List( List.drop(lst,1))));
```

That code doesn't compile with the error of : right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]  expression:

```
'Z generic_list
 result type:  'Z list
 in declaration:
   generic_map =
     (fn (f,List lst) =>
           if lst = nil
           then List nil
           else List
                  (f (List.hd lst) ::
                     generic_map (f,List (List.drop (lst,1)))))
```

I would like to know whats the problem here and how I can fix it so it will compile, I cant find the mistake

Comment: the question is why it doesn't compile of course, i cant understand where the mistake is

Answer (score 2):

In the 'else' part, you do `something :: generic_map (...)`, which implies that `generic_map` would have to return a `list` instead of a `generic_list`.

Also, I don't see where you handle the `seq` case at all.

As a general note, I strongly suggest using pattern matching instead of `if`, `List.hd` and friends. In particular a comparison like `lst = nil` is always wrong, since it restricts the list to elements with equality type -- use pattern matching, or at least the `List.null` predicate.